# How to alter form submmision response text

Tags: forms

How to alter form submmision response text

code below:

```
<?php
function response_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'cmis-upload-node-form')
  {
    //$form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validate_function';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit_function';
  }
}
/*
function my_custom_validate_function($form, &$form_state)
{
  // validate here
}*/

function my_custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state)
{
  // submit here
    drupal_set_message('your Form Submitted Succesfully');
}
?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that the code is formatted properly.

Comment: Instead of editing my question or code, if am getting solution ill be happy :)